# PHP MySQL Database Backup

Tags: php, mysql, backup

Is there an easy php function to backup a database (or set of tables within a database) to another mysql installation or within the same database but to other tables?

Comment: Boy, would my life be easier if there was...

Comment: You can call the "mysqldump" program from PHP.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867797/php-script-to-backup-mysql-database

Comment: You can visit https://codecanyon.net/ and search for "Simple Backup" - you will find several Scripts that fit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php

modify the code to back it up to other database.

Answer (score 2):

No but you could use PHPmyAdmin or any other MySQL tool which supports export. You might also write your own.